# Dirty Read in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

CustomerType entity :

```
public class CustomerType implements java.io.Serializable {

private Integer customerTypeId;
private String customerDesc;
private Set customerInfos = new HashSet(0);

public CustomerType() {
}

public CustomerType(String customerDesc) {
    this.customerDesc = customerDesc;
}

public CustomerType(String customerDesc, Set customerInfos) {
    this.customerDesc = customerDesc;
    this.customerInfos = customerInfos;
}

public Integer getCustomerTypeId() {
    return this.customerTypeId;
}

public void setCustomerTypeId(Integer customerTypeId) {
    this.customerTypeId = customerTypeId;
}
.....................
```

CustomerType has one to many relationship with this entity

```
public class CustomerInfo implements java.io.Serializable {

private Integer customerId;
private CustomerType customerType;
private String name;
    .................................
```

i've a this method in DaoImpl class

```
 @Override
public int save(Object object) {
    try{
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        session.saveOrUpdate(object);
        session.flush();
        transaction.commit();
        return 1;
    }catch (Exception e) {
        transaction.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();// TODO: handle exception
        return 0;
    }
}
```

and i call it while updating an object

```
public String updateCustomerType(){
    this.customertype = this.daoManager.findCustoType(Integer.parseInt(this.customerTypeID));
    this.customertype.setCustomerDesc(this.custoTypeDesc);
    this.daoManager.save(this.customertype);
}
```

This method successfully updating the database, but while i display list of CustomerInfo which has relation to CustomerType, the CustomerType parameter in CustomerInfo is not udpated

```
org.hibernate.Query q = session.createQuery("select customerInfo from CustomerInfo customerInfo");
return q.list();
```

What wrong with mine.,wait for your comment. Thank you,

Comment: wait for your solutions,

Comment: really waiting for your solutions.,

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is that you want to read un-commited data.

I have not tested this on your particular problem but you can try:

```
session.connection().setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED);
```

Also heres an excellent stack to help explain read_uncommited further:

[Why use a READ UNCOMMITTED isolation level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471055/why-use-a-read-uncommitted-isolation-level)