# TSQL Insert Data Linked by Foreign Key

Tags: c#, sql-server, foreign-keys

Let's say I have two tables

**RDB_DataEntities**

```
DataEntityId
Name
Created
Modified
...
```

**RDB_DataInstances**

```
DataInstanceId
DataEntityId
```

So `RDB_DataInstances` is joined to `RDB_DataEntities` via a foreign key on their `DataEntityId` columns.

Let's say I want to insert data into both tables in the same transaction. The code I have for this is as follows:

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection("data source=speedy;initial catalog=mydb;user id=myuser;password=mypass"))
{
   con.Open();

   using (var tran = con.BeginTransaction())
   {
      SqlCommand i1 = new SqlCommand("insert into RDB_DataEntities (Name,IsSchema,Created,Modified,RequireCaptcha,UniqueByEmail,UniqueByMac) values ('hi',0,GetDate(),GetDate(),0,0,0)", con, tran);

      i1.ExecuteNonQuery();

      SqlCommand i2 = new SqlCommand("select SCOPE_IDENTITY() as newid", con, tran);
      var id = int.Parse(i2.ExecuteScalar().ToString());

      SqlCommand i3 = new SqlCommand("insert into RDB_DataInstances (DataEntityId) values (" + id + ")", con, tran);
      i3.ExecuteScalar();
      tran.Commit();
   }
}
```

Why is it throwing a foreign key error

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   'FK_RDB_DataInstances_RDB_DataEntities'. The conflict occurred in
>   database 'NMSS_CMS', table 'dbo.RDB_DataEntities', column
>   'DataEntityId'.

Shouldn't the transaction know that I am inserting the foreign key based upon an insert I just did within the current transaction context? Am I way off?

How do you make this happen?

Comment: It's not happening on your first `INSERT` is it? That is, you haven't set up the FK the wrong way around...

Answer (score 1):

Because `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` will not work when you are using two different command contexts (by definition it is a separate scope). You can append the second query onto the first, and run the `ExecuteScalar()`, like so:

```
SqlCommand i1 = new SqlCommand("insert into RDB_DataEntities (Name,IsSchema,Created,Modified,RequireCaptcha,UniqueByEmail,UniqueByMac) values ('hi',0,GetDate(),GetDate(),0,0,0);select SCOPE_IDENTITY() as newid;",con,tran);                 
var id=int.Parse(i1.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
```

Edit: Just wanted to throw together the T-SQL version of what's going on.

```
DECLARE @newid int

BEGIN TRANSACTION

insert into RDB_DataEntities 
    (Name,IsSchema,Created,Modified,RequireCaptcha,UniqueByEmail,UniqueByMac) 
values 
    ('hi',0,GetDate(),GetDate(),0,0,0)

SELECT @newid = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

insert into RDB_DataInstances 
    (DataEntityId) 
values 
    (@newid)

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Comment: Another solution: use the output clause. Saves yourself a query.

Comment: SCOPE_IDENTITY() definitely works both ways. I've debugged to ensure that my var id definitely has an integer value.

Comment: If you are getting the correct value back, then I'm in agreement that it should work. The T-SQL version of what you are trying to do makes logical sense.

Answer (score 0):

Here's 2 possible solutions for you if I've understood your problem:

1. You could set the transaction isolation level and use READ UNCOMMITTED / NOLOCK to perform a dirty read on the previously inserted record in the transaction (See this post for more [Why use a READ UNCOMMITTED isolation level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471055/why-use-a-read-uncommitted-isolation-level))
2. You could just create the Guid in code and manually insert into the 2 tables as a SqlCommand parameter rather than using `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` after the first insert. (My preferred option)

Answer (score 0):

I dropped the foreign key and recreated it and it started working.