# transactions in SQL

Tags: mysql, transactions

I have two transactions that are the following:

T1:

```
Begin Transaction;
S1: Insert Into Salary Values (103, 60000);
S2: Update Salary Set salary = salary + 10000 Where id = 101;
Commit;
```

T2:

```
Begin Transaction;
S3: Select Avg(salary) As a1 From Salary;
S4: Select Avg(salary) As a2 From Salary;
```

Assume that the individual statements S1, S2, S3, and S4 always execute atomically. Suppose
initially there are two tuples in Salary: (101,30000) and (102,50000). Each transaction runs once and commits. Transaction T1 always executes with isolation level Serializable (the highest level).

**a)**
If transaction T2 executes with isolation level Serializable, what possible pairs of valuesa1 and a2 are returned by T2?

**b)**
If transaction T2 executes with isolation level Read-Committed, what possible pairs of values a1 and a2 are returned by T2?

**c)**
If transaction T2 executes with isolation level Read-Uncommitted what possible pairs of values a1 and a2 are returned by T2?

Here are my answers:

**a)**
S1 – S2 – S3 – S4 Value: a1: 50000 , a2: 50000

S3 – S4 – S1 – S2 Value: a1: 40000, a2: 40000

But I'm a bit confused on how read-committed and how read-uncommitted work. Any help with B and C, would be a great help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471055/why-use-a-read-uncommitted-isolation-level

Answer (score 0):

- read-committed = show only what was already committed (or SAVED IN
  DB)
- read-uncommitted = read what is currently in the database
  (regardless of commit).

given a long transaction, before you issue a "commit" command, all the inserts/updates/deletes cannot be viewed unless you do a "read-uncommitted".  under the hood, the data you insert/update are locked for normal viewing.  sometimes even the entire table is locked - you cannot view any record at all unless you do a read uncommitted.

for fast operations (eg less than 1 sec) you would not really feel the difference between the two but to test the difference, you should open a different connection for the T2 and run T1 without the "commit" command, then you will feel the "lock" on read-committed.