# How to change the LockMode in a DQL query, in Doctrine 2 for SQL Server

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, sql-server-2012

I need to change the LockMode in order to get Doctrine to add the "with(nolock)" behavior to the tables I'm using in the Query.

I'll explain this better:

What I have:

`SELECT e FROM Porject:Example e`

What I want from Doctrine when it creates and executes the SQL:

`SELECT e FROM example e WITH(NOLOCK)`

I can't find how to change the LOCKMODE anywhere, it's becoming a pain.

I tried opening a Transaction and doing the `setLockMode(LockMode::NONE)` but it just adds the `with(nolock)` after the first table (the one in the FROM clause) and I need it to add it in every table (the ones on the JOINs).

What I really have:

`SELECT e, o FROM Porject:Example e JOIN e.owner o`

What I did:

```
  $dql='SELECT e, o FROM Porject:Example e JOIN e.owner o';
  $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery($dql);
  try{
     $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->beginTransaction();
     $result = $query ->setLockMode(LockMode::NONE)->getSQL();
     $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->commit();
  } catch (\Exception $e) {
     $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->rollback();
     throw $e;
  }
```

Being the `$result`:

```
SELECT c0_.prop1, c0_.prop2, c1_.prop1, c1_.prop2 
FROM examples c0_ WITH(NOLOCK) 
INNER JOIN owners c1_ ON c1_.id= c0_ownerId`
```

And what I was expecting:

```
SELECT c0_.prop1, c0_.prop2, c1_.prop1, c1_.prop2 
FROM examples c0_ WITH(NOLOCK) 
INNER JOIN owners c1_ WITH(NOLOCK) ON c1_.id= c0_ownerId`
```

Notice the double `WITH(NOLOCK)`

**Possible Solution:**

```
try {
    $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->beginTransaction();
    $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->setTransactionIsolation(\Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED);
    $result = $query->getArrayResult();
    $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->commit();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->rollback();
    throw $e;
}
```

But I'm not sure if it's the same to do the `with(nolock)` than using the `READ_UNCOMMITTED` *isolation level*.

Settings @chalasr's answer as the accepted one. Created another question to solve the actual problem: [How perform lockmode:none on associations (join) with Doctrine2 and SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35431825/how-perform-lockmodenone-on-associations-join-with-doctrine2-and-sql-server)

Just for reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is 4 different [`LockMode`](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/dbal/2.2/class-Doctrine.DBAL.LockMode.html) :

```
const NONE = 0;
const OPTIMISTIC = 1;
const PESSIMISTIC_READ = 2;
const PESSIMISTIC_WRITE = 4;
```

Find the most appropriated in the [documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html#locking-support) and use like this :

```
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT e FROM Porject:Example e');
$query->setLockMode(LockMode::NONE);
```

Comment: I was just trying that but it complains with an: "An open transaction is required for this operation.".

Comment: Update my first POST with the new state. Problem is not fully solved.

Comment: Ah, it's really a different problem ... Look for cut your query in two to set the lock mode for each, I'll look for and come back to you.

Comment: You should open another question for how perform lockmode on associations (join)

Comment: I tried with a different aproach, I don't know if it's fully equivalent (edited the first post). Thanks a lot.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471055/why-use-a-read-uncommitted-isolation-level