# How perform lockmode:none on associations (join) with Doctrine2 and SQL Server

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, sql-server-2012, nolock

I'm trying to append the With(nolock) hint to my Queries using Doctrine2. I tried using the `->setLockMode(LockMode::NONE)->getSQL();` but it didn't work as expected, it added the WITH(NOLOCK) just to the (**first**) table in the FROM clause. I'll explain:

```
$dql='SELECT e, o FROM Porject:Example e JOIN e.owner o';
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery($dql);
try{
   $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->beginTransaction();
   $result = $query ->setLockMode(LockMode::NONE)->getSQL();
   $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->commit();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
   $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->rollback();
   throw $e;
}
```

Expected:

```
SELECT c0_.prop1, c0_.prop2, c1_.prop1, c1_.prop2 
FROM examples c0_ WITH(NOLOCK) 
INNER JOIN owners c1_ WITH(NOLOCK) ON c1_.id= c0_ownerId`
```

What I truly got:

```
SELECT c0_.prop1, c0_.prop2, c1_.prop1, c1_.prop2 
FROM examples c0_ WITH(NOLOCK) 
INNER JOIN owners c1_ ON c1_.id= c0_ownerId`
```

**Possible Solution:**

```
try {
    $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->beginTransaction();
    $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->setTransactionIsolation(\Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED);
    $result = $query->getArrayResult();
    $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->commit();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->rollback();
    throw $e;
}
```

But I'm not sure if it's the same to do the `with(nolock)` than using the `READ_UNCOMMITTED` *isolation level*.

Edit: Starting the *transaction* as posted with the `TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED` is the same as doing the *with(nolock)* on **every table** of the query.

Comment: Did you found a solution? I've got the same problem.

Comment: Yes I did. As I posted in the OP it's the same as opening a transtaction with the TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED flag.

Comment: Thanks, that's what i want to hear ;-).

Comment: "READ UNCOMMITTED: This option has the same effect as setting NOLOCK on all tables in all SELECT statements in a transaction. This is the least restrictive of the isolation levels." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments