# Difference between WITH READ UNCOMMITED and Setting Transaction iso level

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server

Let's say I have a view within an enterprise application. This view is used to build a data set, and it will be called from a stored procedure and eventually return the data set to the C# ASP.NET MVC layer.

What is the difference between adding this code once, at the top of the view:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
```

vs adding `WITH READ UNCOMMITTED` or `WITH (NOLOCK)` on every table like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM State WITH (READUNCOMMITTED) 
JOIN City WITH (READUNCOMMITTED) ON City.StateID = State.StateID
JOIN Street WITH (READUNCOMMITTED) ON Street.CityID = City.CityID
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why use a READ UNCOMMITTED isolation level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471055/why-use-a-read-uncommitted-isolation-level)

Comment: See [Bad Habits to kick - putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/) - it is *not recommended* to use this everywhere - quite the contrary!

Answer (score 2):

`SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED` doesn't become part of the view.  That simply sets the isolation level for you current connection.  Anyone using the view won't have that setting applied.

Comment: To make this more clear - you CANNOT set the isolation level in a view. A view consists of a single sql statement and the "set transaction isolation level ..." approach requires 2 statements.