# Query grows slower as user activity increases

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, query-optimization, user-activity

The query below takes  0.6748seconds to execute, but when there are many users attempting to do the same activity at the same time, the processes becomes very slow and takes about 30seconds to execute.

Server Bandwidth: 7TB

I have made several attempts to optimize the query and the performance improved, but as the database grew larger, the performance has declined again, I am left with no more option to try.

Please assist to help optimize my query further

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM
                    (SELECT
                         c.loan_id ,c.channel tu_channel, c.user_unique_id tu_user_unique_id ,c.ippis tu_ippis ,c.top_up_approved, c.ret_customer_bal ,c.loan_type tu_loan_type ,c.dse ,c.status ,c.current_loan tu_current_loan ,c.record_category ,c.date_created tu_date_created ,c.date_updated tu_date_updated , a.id ,a.user_unique_id ,a.loan_location ,a.ippis ,a.tel_no ,a.organisation ,a.branch ,a.loan_agree ,a.loan_type ,a.appr ,a.sold ,a.loan_status , a.channel, a.top_up ,a.current_loan, a.retrieved_customer_bal ,a.date_created ,a.date_updated 
                    FROM
                        loan_applications_tbl a 
                    LEFT JOIN
                        topup_or_reapplication_tbl AS c 
                            ON a.ippis = c.ippis 
                    WHERE
                        (
                            (
                                (
                                    (
                                        a.current_loan = '0' 
                                        AND a.loan_status IN (
                                            'Approved', 'Closed'
                                        )
                                    )
                                ) 
                                AND (
                                    ((a.loan_status='pending' 
                            AND a.appr < 500000) OR ( a.loan_status IN ( 'corrected', 'Approved By Group Head', 'NIL', 
                    'NIL', 'NIL', 'NIL' )  )) 
                                ) 
                                AND (
                                    (
                                        MONTH(a.date_updated) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE) 
                                        AND YEAR(a.date_updated) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        ) 
                    UNION ALL 
                    SELECT
                         c.loan_id ,c.channel tu_channel, c.user_unique_id tu_user_unique_id ,c.ippis tu_ippis ,c.top_up_approved, c.ret_customer_bal ,c.loan_type tu_loan_type ,c.dse ,c.status ,c.current_loan tu_current_loan ,c.record_category ,c.date_created tu_date_created ,c.date_updated tu_date_updated, b.loan_id ,b.user_unique_id ,b.loan_location ,b.ippis ,b.tel_no ,b.organisation ,b.branch ,b.loan_agree ,b.loan_type ,b.appr ,b.sold ,b.loan_status ,b.channel, b.top_up ,b.current_loan, b.retrieved_customer_bal ,b.date_created ,b.date_updated 
                    FROM
                        loan_applications_tbl_dump b 
                    LEFT JOIN
                        topup_or_reapplication_tbl c 
                            ON b.ippis = c.ippis 
                    WHERE
                        (
                            (
                                (
                                    (
                                        b.current_loan = '0' 
                                        AND b.loan_status IN (
                                            'Approved', 'Closed'
                                        )
                                    )
                                ) 
                                AND (
                                    ((b.loan_status='pending' 
                            AND b.appr < 500000) OR (b.loan_status IN ( 'corrected', 'Approved By Group Head', 'NIL', 
                        'NIL', 'NIL', 'NIL' ) )) 
                                ) 
                                AND (
                                    (
                                        MONTH(b.date_updated) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE) 
                                        AND YEAR(b.date_updated) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        ) 
                    UNION DISTINCT 
                    SELECT
                         c.loan_id ,c.channel tu_channel, c.user_unique_id tu_user_unique_id ,c.ippis tu_ippis ,c.top_up_approved, c.ret_customer_bal ,c.loan_type tu_loan_type ,c.dse ,c.status ,c.current_loan tu_current_loan ,c.record_category ,c.date_created tu_date_created ,c.date_updated tu_date_updated , a.id ,a.user_unique_id ,a.loan_location ,a.ippis ,a.tel_no ,a.organisation ,a.branch ,a.loan_agree ,a.loan_type ,a.appr ,a.sold ,a.loan_status , a.channel, a.top_up ,a.current_loan, a.retrieved_customer_bal ,a.date_created ,a.date_updated 
                    FROM
                        loan_applications_tbl a 
                    INNER JOIN
                        topup_or_reapplication_tbl AS c 
                            ON a.ippis = c.ippis 
                    WHERE
                        (
                            (
                                c.current_loan = '1' 
                                AND (
                                    ((c.status='pending' 
                            AND c.top_up_approved < 500000)  OR (c.status IN ('corrected', 'Approved By Group Head', 'NIL', 
                        'NIL', 'NIL', 'NIL') )) 
                                ) 
                                AND (
                                    (
                                        MONTH(c.date_updated) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE) 
                                        AND YEAR(c.date_updated) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        ) 
                    UNION
                    DISTINCT SELECT
                         c.loan_id ,c.channel tu_channel, c.user_unique_id tu_user_unique_id ,c.ippis tu_ippis ,c.top_up_approved, c.ret_customer_bal ,c.loan_type tu_loan_type ,c.dse ,c.status ,c.current_loan tu_current_loan ,c.record_category ,c.date_created tu_date_created ,c.date_updated tu_date_updated, b.loan_id ,b.user_unique_id ,b.loan_location ,b.ippis ,b.tel_no ,b.organisation ,b.branch ,b.loan_agree ,b.loan_type ,b.appr ,b.sold ,b.loan_status ,b.channel, b.top_up ,b.current_loan, b.retrieved_customer_bal ,b.date_created ,b.date_updated 
                    FROM
                        loan_applications_tbl_dump b 
                    INNER JOIN
                        topup_or_reapplication_tbl c 
                            ON b.ippis = c.ippis 
                    WHERE
                        (
                            (
                                c.current_loan = '1' 
                                AND (
                                    ((c.status='pending' 
                            AND c.top_up_approved < 500000)  OR (c.status IN ('corrected', 'Approved By Group Head', 'NIL', 
                        'NIL', 'NIL', 'NIL') )) 
                                ) 
                                AND (
                                    (
                                        MONTH(c.date_updated) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE) 
                                        AND YEAR(c.date_updated) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        ) 
                    UNION
                    DISTINCT SELECT
                         c.loan_id ,c.channel tu_channel, c.user_unique_id tu_user_unique_id ,c.ippis tu_ippis ,c.top_up_approved, c.ret_customer_bal ,c.loan_type tu_loan_type ,c.dse ,c.status ,c.current_loan tu_current_loan ,c.record_category ,c.date_created tu_date_created ,c.date_updated tu_date_updated , a.id ,a.user_unique_id ,a.loan_location ,a.ippis ,a.tel_no ,a.organisation ,a.branch ,a.loan_agree ,a.loan_type ,a.appr ,a.sold ,a.loan_status , a.channel, a.top_up ,a.current_loan, a.retrieved_customer_bal ,a.date_created ,a.date_updated 
                    FROM
                        loan_applications_tbl a 
                    LEFT JOIN
                        topup_or_reapplication_tbl AS c 
                            ON a.ippis = c.ippis 
                    WHERE
                        (
                            (
                                (
                                    a.current_loan = '1'
                                ) 
                                AND (
                                    ((a.loan_status='pending' 
                            AND a.appr < 500000) OR ( a.loan_status IN ( 'corrected', 'Approved By Group Head', 'NIL', 
                    'NIL', 'NIL', 'NIL' )  )) 
                                ) 
                                AND (
                                    (
                                        MONTH(a.date_updated) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE) 
                                        AND YEAR(a.date_updated) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        ) 
                    UNION
                    DISTINCT SELECT
                         c.loan_id ,c.channel tu_channel, c.user_unique_id tu_user_unique_id ,c.ippis tu_ippis ,c.top_up_approved, c.ret_customer_bal ,c.loan_type tu_loan_type ,c.dse ,c.status ,c.current_loan tu_current_loan ,c.record_category ,c.date_created tu_date_created ,c.date_updated tu_date_updated, b.loan_id ,b.user_unique_id ,b.loan_location ,b.ippis ,b.tel_no ,b.organisation ,b.branch ,b.loan_agree ,b.loan_type ,b.appr ,b.sold ,b.loan_status ,b.channel, b.top_up ,b.current_loan, b.retrieved_customer_bal ,b.date_created ,b.date_updated 
                    FROM
                        loan_applications_tbl_dump b 
                    LEFT JOIN
                        topup_or_reapplication_tbl c 
                            ON b.ippis = c.ippis 
                    WHERE
                        (
                            (
                                (
                                    b.current_loan = '1'
                                ) 
                                AND (
                                    ((b.loan_status='pending' 
                            AND b.appr < 500000) OR (b.loan_status IN ( 'corrected', 'Approved By Group Head', 'NIL', 
                        'NIL', 'NIL', 'NIL' ) )) 
                                ) 
                                AND (
                                    (
                                        MONTH(b.date_updated) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE) 
                                        AND YEAR(b.date_updated) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        ) 
                    UNION
                    DISTINCT SELECT
                         c.loan_id ,c.channel tu_channel, c.user_unique_id tu_user_unique_id ,c.ippis tu_ippis ,c.top_up_approved, c.ret_customer_bal ,c.loan_type tu_loan_type ,c.dse ,c.status ,c.current_loan tu_current_loan ,c.record_category ,c.date_created tu_date_created ,c.date_updated tu_date_updated , a.id ,a.user_unique_id ,a.loan_location ,a.ippis ,a.tel_no ,a.organisation ,a.branch ,a.loan_agree ,a.loan_type ,a.appr ,a.sold ,a.loan_status , a.channel, a.top_up ,a.current_loan, a.retrieved_customer_bal ,a.date_created ,a.date_updated 
                    FROM
                        loan_applications_tbl a 
                    INNER JOIN
                        topup_or_reapplication_tbl AS c 
                            ON a.ippis = c.ippis 
                    WHERE
                        (
                            (
                                c.current_loan = '1' 
                                AND (
                                    ((c.status='pending' 
                            AND c.top_up_approved < 500000)  OR (c.status IN ('corrected', 'Approved By Group Head', 'NIL', 
                        'NIL', 'NIL', 'NIL') )) 
                                ) 
                                AND (
                                    (
                                        MONTH(c.date_created) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE) 
                                        AND YEAR(c.date_created) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        ) 
                    UNION
                    DISTINCT SELECT
                         c.loan_id ,c.channel tu_channel, c.user_unique_id tu_user_unique_id ,c.ippis tu_ippis ,c.top_up_approved, c.ret_customer_bal ,c.loan_type tu_loan_type ,c.dse ,c.status ,c.current_loan tu_current_loan ,c.record_category ,c.date_created tu_date_created ,c.date_updated tu_date_updated, b.loan_id ,b.user_unique_id ,b.loan_location ,b.ippis ,b.tel_no ,b.organisation ,b.branch ,b.loan_agree ,b.loan_type ,b.appr ,b.sold ,b.loan_status ,b.channel, b.top_up ,b.current_loan, b.retrieved_customer_bal ,b.date_created ,b.date_updated 
                    FROM
                        loan_applications_tbl_dump b 
                    INNER JOIN
                        topup_or_reapplication_tbl c 
                            ON b.ippis = c.ippis 
                    WHERE
                        (
                            (
                                c.current_loan = '1' 
                                AND (
                                    ((c.status='pending' 
                            AND c.top_up_approved < 500000)  OR (c.status IN ('corrected', 'Approved By Group Head', 'NIL', 
                        'NIL', 'NIL', 'NIL') )) 
                                ) 
                                AND (
                                    (
                                        MONTH(c.date_created) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE) 
                                        AND YEAR(c.date_created) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        ) 
                    UNION
                    DISTINCT SELECT
                         c.loan_id ,c.channel tu_channel, c.user_unique_id tu_user_unique_id ,c.ippis tu_ippis ,c.top_up_approved, c.ret_customer_bal ,c.loan_type tu_loan_type ,c.dse ,c.status ,c.current_loan tu_current_loan ,c.record_category ,c.date_created tu_date_created ,c.date_updated tu_date_updated , a.id ,a.user_unique_id ,a.loan_location ,a.ippis ,a.tel_no ,a.organisation ,a.branch ,a.loan_agree ,a.loan_type ,a.appr ,a.sold ,a.loan_status , a.channel, a.top_up ,a.current_loan, a.retrieved_customer_bal ,a.date_created ,a.date_updated 
                    FROM
                        loan_applications_tbl a 
                    LEFT JOIN
                        topup_or_reapplication_tbl AS c 
                            ON a.ippis = c.ippis 
                    WHERE
                        (
                            (
                                (
                                    (
                                        a.current_loan = '0' 
                                        AND a.loan_status IN (
                                            'Approved', 'Closed'
                                        )
                                    )
                                ) 
                                AND (
                                    ((a.loan_status='pending' 
                            AND a.appr < 500000) OR ( a.loan_status IN ( 'corrected', 'Approved By Group Head', 'NIL', 
                    'NIL', 'NIL', 'NIL' )  )) 
                                ) 
                                AND (
                                    (
                                        MONTH(a.date_created) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE) 
                                        AND YEAR(a.date_created) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        ) 
                    UNION
                    DISTINCT SELECT
                         c.loan_id ,c.channel tu_channel, c.user_unique_id tu_user_unique_id ,c.ippis tu_ippis ,c.top_up_approved, c.ret_customer_bal ,c.loan_type tu_loan_type ,c.dse ,c.status ,c.current_loan tu_current_loan ,c.record_category ,c.date_created tu_date_created ,c.date_updated tu_date_updated, b.loan_id ,b.user_unique_id ,b.loan_location ,b.ippis ,b.tel_no ,b.organisation ,b.branch ,b.loan_agree ,b.loan_type ,b.appr ,b.sold ,b.loan_status ,b.channel, b.top_up ,b.current_loan, b.retrieved_customer_bal ,b.date_created ,b.date_updated 
                    FROM
                        loan_applications_tbl_dump b 
                    LEFT JOIN
                        topup_or_reapplication_tbl c 
                            ON b.ippis = c.ippis 
                    WHERE
                        (
                            (
                                (
                                    (
                                        b.current_loan = '0' 
                                        AND b.loan_status IN (
                                            'Approved', 'Closed'
                                        )
                                    )
                                ) 
                                AND (
                                    ((b.loan_status='pending' 
                            AND b.appr < 500000) OR (b.loan_status IN ( 'corrected', 'Approved By Group Head', 'NIL', 
                        'NIL', 'NIL', 'NIL' ) )) 
                                ) 
                                AND (
                                    (
                                        MONTH(b.date_created) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE) 
                                        AND YEAR(b.date_created) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        ) 
                    UNION
                    DISTINCT SELECT
                         c.loan_id ,c.channel tu_channel, c.user_unique_id tu_user_unique_id ,c.ippis tu_ippis ,c.top_up_approved, c.ret_customer_bal ,c.loan_type tu_loan_type ,c.dse ,c.status ,c.current_loan tu_current_loan ,c.record_category ,c.date_created tu_date_created ,c.date_updated tu_date_updated , a.id ,a.user_unique_id ,a.loan_location ,a.ippis ,a.tel_no ,a.organisation ,a.branch ,a.loan_agree ,a.loan_type ,a.appr ,a.sold ,a.loan_status , a.channel, a.top_up ,a.current_loan, a.retrieved_customer_bal ,a.date_created ,a.date_updated 
                    FROM
                        loan_applications_tbl a 
                    LEFT JOIN
                        topup_or_reapplication_tbl AS c 
                            ON a.ippis = c.ippis 
                    WHERE
                        (
                            (
                                (
                                    a.current_loan = '1'
                                ) 
                                AND (
                                    ((a.loan_status='pending' 
                            AND a.appr < 500000) OR ( a.loan_status IN ( 'corrected', 'Approved By Group Head', 'NIL', 
                    'NIL', 'NIL', 'NIL' )  )) 
                                ) 
                                AND (
                                    (
                                        MONTH(a.date_created) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE) 
                                        AND YEAR(a.date_created) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        ) 
                    UNION
                    DISTINCT SELECT
                         c.loan_id ,c.channel tu_channel, c.user_unique_id tu_user_unique_id ,c.ippis tu_ippis ,c.top_up_approved, c.ret_customer_bal ,c.loan_type tu_loan_type ,c.dse ,c.status ,c.current_loan tu_current_loan ,c.record_category ,c.date_created tu_date_created ,c.date_updated tu_date_updated, b.loan_id ,b.user_unique_id ,b.loan_location ,b.ippis ,b.tel_no ,b.organisation ,b.branch ,b.loan_agree ,b.loan_type ,b.appr ,b.sold ,b.loan_status ,b.channel, b.top_up ,b.current_loan, b.retrieved_customer_bal ,b.date_created ,b.date_updated 
                    FROM
                        loan_applications_tbl_dump b 
                    LEFT JOIN
                        topup_or_reapplication_tbl c 
                            ON b.ippis = c.ippis 
                    WHERE
                        (
                            (
                                (
                                    b.current_loan = '1'
                                ) 
                                AND (
                                    ((b.loan_status='pending' 
                            AND b.appr < 500000) OR (b.loan_status IN ( 'corrected', 'Approved By Group Head', 'NIL', 
                        'NIL', 'NIL', 'NIL' ) )) 
                                ) 
                                AND (
                                    (
                                        MONTH(b.date_created) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE) 
                                        AND YEAR(b.date_created) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    ) t3 ORDER BY t3.date_updated, t3.tu_date_updated DESC LIMIT 18446744073709551615) AS t4 GROUP BY t4.ippis
```

EXPLAIN statement gives me the table below:
[image]

Comment: pls show the **EXPLAIN** OF YOUR QUERY

Comment: @BerndBuffen The table in the image above shows the EXPLAIN of the query

Comment: Did you check the server load avarage when there are many users loged on?

Comment: @ErgestBasha overall CPU usage has been less than 30%. Server internet speed is about 1.6Gbps., the number of users logged in per time are less than 100

Comment: @Peter - can you post the result from **SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;** when the server use long time

Comment: @BerndBuffen User activity is lesser on the application now, I will post this required information as soon as the server slows, are there other things I can try, pending the time I am able to get that information?

Comment: @Peter - is it possible to send me a sql dump of your tables with create tables to my e-mail. you can find it in my profile. the i can optimize your query. i am also want to see the server my.cnf and version of mysql/mariadb server

Comment: @BerndBuffen doing that in a moment, thanks a lot

Comment: @Peter, did you want to send me something else? 
I haven't received anything yet

Comment: Please post SHOW CREATE TABLE (for a b c); so we can see your current structure and we will also know the indexes you have available at this time.

Comment: @Bernd Buffen please accept my apologies for the delay, my schedule has been traumatic. But I'm back on this now, sending an email in a moment

Comment: @WilsonHauck Well noted

Comment: @peter          Does 'Well noted' mean you will post SHOW CREATE TABLE (for a b c) as requested - when time permits?

Answer (score 1):

That's a very large query.  Maybe even too large for a Stack Overflow question.

1. I suggest you try optimizing one of the subqueries at a time (one of the arms of your UNION operation). That way you don't have to think about the whole mess at once.
2. Use [UNION ALL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html#union-distinct-all) rather than UNION DISTINCT if you can; UNION DISTINCT deduplicates its result set and that takes cpu time and RAM.
3. You have this WHERE-clause pattern recurring several times.

   ```sql
       MONTH(a.date_updated) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE)
   AND YEAR(a.date_updated) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)
   ```

   It's not [sargable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable).  That is, it's written to defeat the use of an index on `loan_applications_tbl.date_updated`.  Use this equivalent instead. If you do MySQL will be able to do a [range scan](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/range-optimization.html) on the index.

   ```sql
       a.date_updated >= LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE) + 1 DAY - 1 MONTH
   AND a.date_updated <  LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE) + 1 DAY
   ```

   [LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day) gets you midnight on the last day of the month, and the rest of the date arithmetic gets midnight on the first day of the present month and midnight on the first day of the next month.
4. You didn't tell us anything about your indexes. Your query has ORs which make them slower, so you'll have to experiment with this.  Try creating this index, if you don't have it already.

   ```sql
   ALTER TABLE loan_applications_tbl 
    ADD INDEX cur_stat_date 
              (current_loan, loan_status, date_updated, appr)
   ```

   It might help, as it allows MySQL to random-access the index I suggested, then read it sequentially.

   You'll need a similar index on `loan_applications_tbl_dump`.
5. When you have a lot of users, you may be seeing contention. If your application can tolerate retrieving data that may not be exactly right for rows that are currently being inserted and updated, give this command right before your query.

   ```sql
   SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
   ```

   This can be a bit [risky for data integrity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471055/why-use-a-read-uncommitted-isolation-level) if your application uses a lot of transaction. But it will reduce contention.
6. Can you refactor the query to be less repetitive?

Comment: thanks for your help, I will try these options and report on my progress

Answer (score 0):

These might help:

```
c:  INDEX(current_loan, status, top_up_approved, ippis)
a, b:  INDEX(current_loan, loan_status, appr, ippis)
```

Splitting up a date is usually inefficient:

```
AND  MONTH(b.date_created) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE)
AND  YEAR(b.date_created) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)
```

-->

```
AND b.date_created >= LEFT(CURDATE(), 7)
```

That should allow for these indexes to be useful:

```
b, c:  INDEX(current_loan, date_created, ippis)
```

That may speed things up by *starting* with c