# Multiple instances of Azure function writing (insert / update) to Azure SQL database are throwing deadlock exception

Tags: azure-functions, azure-sql-database

When Azure function is scaled up to multiple instances, it starts throwing a deadlock exception:

> Exception: ('40001', '[40001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Transaction (Process ID 878) was deadlocked on lock | communication buffer resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction. (1205) (SQLExecDirectW)')

Comment: See if this article will help you create a question with enough details to be answered: https://sqljana.wordpress.com/2020/03/17/sql-server-fix-transaction-process-id-was-deadlocked-on-lock-communication-buffer-resources-with-another-process-and-has-been-chosen-as-the-deadlock-victim-rerun-the-transaction/

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, Try with this command. `set transaction isolation level read uncommitted;`. This isolation level allows dirty reads. One transaction may see uncommitted changes made by some other transaction.

Please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471055/why-use-a-read-uncommitted-isolation-level) by [@Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/222908/daniel-vassallo) for more details on same.

Also consider this [official document1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb4537649-fix-deadlock-may-occur-when-you-create-a-database-by-using-non-default-collation-in-sql-server-2017-edb7f3fd-46a3-0280-f17b-f5647e46140f), [document2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb4506912-fix-concurrent-inserts-into-a-cci-can-cause-deadlock-under-memory-pressure-in-sql-server-2016-and-2017-3b73121c-345e-601c-61c8-b7a9ccaa96cf).